# Pygame problem falling objects doesnt show up

Tags: python, image, pygame

Hey can someone tell me why I dont see the objects falling from the top? In this case The "Münzen, Scheine, and Sack". I am new to pygame and maybe there is an easy way. My game should be like this:

The walking man should catch money falling down and get points for it.

https://gyazo.com/d2ce52cb54e8658e92ae9e5f3d1e7cca

`````
import random
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
pygame.init()

#Display
win = pygame.display.set_mode((900,780))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Collector")

#Laufanimation
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Assets/R1.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R2.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R3.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R4.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R5.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R6.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R7.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R8.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Assets/L1.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L2.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L3.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L4.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L5.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L6.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L7.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L8.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/L9.png')]

#Hintergrund
bg = pygame.image.load('City.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (900,780))

#Charakter
char = pygame.image.load('Assets/R1.png')

# Geld
Münzen2 = pygame.image.load("Assets/coin.png")
Schein2 = pygame.image.load("Assets/schein.png")
Sack2 = pygame.image.load("Assets/sack.png")

# Geld
Münzen = pygame.image.load("Assets/coin.png")
Schein = pygame.image.load("Assets/schein.png")
Sack = pygame.image.load("Assets/sack.png")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player():
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 20
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            win.blit(char, (self.x,self.y))

        self.hitbox = (self.x + 215, self.y + 230, 220, 70) # NEW
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)


    
    
class Laser:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = img

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def off_screen(self, height):
        return not(self.y <= height and self.y >= 0)

    def collision(self, obj):
        return collide(self, obj)


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    collector.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

class Ship:
    COOLDOWN = 30

    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.draw(window)

    def move_lasers(self, vel, obj):
        self.cooldown()
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.move(vel)
            if laser.off_screen(HEIGHT):
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
            elif laser.collision(obj):
                obj.health -= 10
                self.lasers.remove(laser)

    def cooldown(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter >= self.COOLDOWN:
            self.cool_down_counter = 0
        elif self.cool_down_counter > 0:
            self.cool_down_counter += 1

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x, self.y, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1

    def get_width(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_width()

    def get_height(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_height()        

        

class Enemy(Ship):
    COLOR_MAP = {
                "red": (Münzen, Münzen2),
                "green": (Schein, Schein2),
                "blue": (Sack, Sack2)
                }

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOR_MAP[color]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x-20, self.y, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1


def collide(obj1, obj2):
    offset_x = obj2.x - obj1.x
    offset_y = obj2.y - obj1.y
    return obj1.mask.overlap(obj2.mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None


#mainloop
collector = player(200, 410, 64,64)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and collector.x > -180 -collector.width -collector.vel:
        collector.x -= collector.vel
        collector.left = True
        collector.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and collector.x < 550 - collector.width - collector.vel:
        collector.x += collector.vel
        collector.right = True
        collector.left = False
    else:
       collector.right = False
       collector.left = False
       collector.walkCount = 0    


    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYFkB.png
`````

Comment: Please try and be more specific about what your problem is

Comment: It is unlikely you will get an answer to a question that is just "make this work for me". I would consider trying to break down your code, taking it step-by-step and figuring out a particular problem you are having. Then you can edit this question to give it more clarity

Comment: I dont wanna ask for making it work for me. I just try to understand the problem because there is no error code or something but the icons arent just showing up.

Comment: The images don't show up because you have to actually draw them to the screen. I'll add an answer explaining more.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questing by removing the code, please.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you copy/pasted your code together, so let's drop it and start from scratch. Feel free to look some stuff up the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) as we go along.

First, we need a mainloop to keep our game running. I usually start with something like this:

```
import pygame

RESOLUTION = 800, 600
FPS = 60

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    dt, clock = 0, pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill('black')
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will create a window and manage our sprites that we will create later on and add to the `sprites` container. Not much to see here currently:

[image]

Now, we want a player that can move left and right. Here's how I would do it, making use of some pygame features, like the `Rect` and `Sprite` class. There's no magic involved. A `Sprite` is basically just a class that has an `image` attribute (you already guessed that this is, well, the image to use), and a `rect` attribute, with contains the position of where we want to draw the image.

Here's the `Player` class:

```
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 600

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill('dodgerblue')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, dt, events):
        d = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: d -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: d += 1

        self.rect.move_ip(d * dt * PLAYER_SPEED, 0)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.rect.clamp_ip(display_rect)
```

and now let's add a `Player` to our game:

```
...
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
Player((300, 500), sprites)
while True:
...
```

[image]

Note that you don't have to draw/blit anything manually. Give our class an `image` and `rect` attribute, subclass `Sprite`, add the instance to a `Group`, and call `draw` on this group.

Now for the falling coins and other stuff. We should create a class for them, something like this:

```
from random import choice
FALLING_SPEED = 400

class FallingStuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(choice(['red', 'yellow', 'green']))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, dt, events):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, FALLING_SPEED * dt)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        if self.rect.top > display_rect.bottom:
            self.kill()
```

In your final game, you can easily replace the mono coloured `image` with an image you loaded from a file. Here, I just randomly choose red, yellow or green.

As you have already guessed, all the behaviour of our game objects is inside the `update` method of the sprite classes. The `FallingStuff` just moves its `rect` downward and kills itself when it goes out of screen. 'killing' as sprite just means it removes itself from all of its `Group`-containers. Another reason to use these instead of plain lists.

Of course, we want to generate multiple falling objects. There are dozen ways to do this but let's use pygame's `time` module to create an event because why not:

```
from random import randint
...
CREATE_STUFF = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if e.type == CREATE_STUFF:
            pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
            FallingStuff((randint(50, 550), -TILESIZE), sprites)
    screen.fill('black')
    sprites.update(dt, events)
    sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
```

[image]

The only thing left is to check if we could catch one of the falling objects.

Full code below:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from random import choice, randint

RESOLUTION = 800, 600
FPS = 60
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 600
FALLING_SPEED = 400

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, falling_stuff, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill('dodgerblue')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.falling_stuff = falling_stuff
        self.score = 0

    def update(self, dt, events):
        d = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: d -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: d += 1

        self.rect.move_ip(d * dt * PLAYER_SPEED, 0)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.rect.clamp_ip(display_rect)

        for stuff in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.falling_stuff, True):
            self.score += 1

class FallingStuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(choice(['red', 'yellow', 'green']))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, dt, events):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, FALLING_SPEED * dt)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        if self.rect.top > display_rect.bottom:
            self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    dt, clock = 0, pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    falling_stuff = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((300, 500), falling_stuff, sprites)
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 54)

    CREATE_STUFF = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == CREATE_STUFF:
                pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
                FallingStuff((randint(50, 550), -TILESIZE), falling_stuff, sprites)
        screen.fill('black')
        font.render_to(screen, (20, 20), f'Score: {player.score}', 'white')
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

And here's the same with animations and a hitbox:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import os
from random import choice, randint
from itertools import cycle

RESOLUTION = 800, 600
FPS = 60
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 300
FALLING_SPEED = 400
ANIM_THRESHOLD = 0.05

def load_images(dir):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(path, dir)
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        yield pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, f)).convert_alpha()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, falling_stuff, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        idle_images = list(load_images('1-Idle'))
        run_images = list(load_images('2-Run'))
        self.images = {
            'IDLE': {
                'RIGHT': cycle(idle_images),
                'LEFT': cycle(pygame.transform.flip(s, True, False) for s in idle_images)
            },
            'RUN': {
                'RIGHT': cycle(run_images),
                'LEFT': cycle(pygame.transform.flip(s, True, False) for s in run_images)
            }
        }
        self.state = 'IDLE'
        self.direction = 'RIGHT'
        self.image = next(self.images['IDLE']['RIGHT'])
        self.animation_counter = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.falling_stuff = falling_stuff
        self.score = 0
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 20)
        self.hitbox.center = self.rect.center
        self.hitbox.move_ip(-10, -10)

    def update_image(self, dt, new_state):
        self.animation_counter += dt
        if self.animation_counter > ANIM_THRESHOLD or self.state != new_state:
            self.image = next(self.images[new_state][self.direction])
            self.animation_counter = 0

    def update(self, dt, events):
        d = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: d -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: d += 1

        self.rect.move_ip(d * dt * PLAYER_SPEED, 0)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.rect.clamp_ip(display_rect)

        if d == 1:
            new_state = 'RUN'
            self.direction = 'RIGHT'
        if d == -1:
            new_state = 'RUN'
            self.direction = 'LEFT'
        if d == 0:
            new_state = 'IDLE'

        for stuff in self.falling_stuff:
            if self.hitbox.colliderect(stuff.rect):
                stuff.kill()
                self.score += 1

        self.update_image(dt, new_state)
        self.state = new_state
        
        self.hitbox.center = self.rect.center
        self.hitbox.move_ip(10 if self.direction == 'LEFT' else -10, -10)
        pygame.draw.rect(pygame.display.get_surface(), 'red', self.hitbox, 2)

class FallingStuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(choice(['red', 'yellow', 'green']))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, dt, events):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, FALLING_SPEED * dt)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        if self.rect.top > display_rect.bottom:
            self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    dt, clock = 0, pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    falling_stuff = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((300, 500), falling_stuff, sprites)
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 54)

    CREATE_STUFF = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == CREATE_STUFF:
                pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
                FallingStuff((randint(50, 550), -TILESIZE), falling_stuff, sprites)
        screen.fill('black')
        font.render_to(screen, (20, 20), f'Score: {player.score}', 'white')
        sprites.draw(screen)
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

[*Sprites by Pixel Frog*](https://pixelfrog-store.itch.io/pirate-bomb)

Comment: That is the kind of answer you want to get when you ask a question on stackoverflow! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xAskadia just saying "the game crashes" is not helpful. There's an error message and that error message tells us what's wrong. I think your problem is that the load function takes a single parameter, but you try to pass two.

Comment: @sloth Can u tell me where i have to chance the rect, so i can put in my pictures? Bc when i write "super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(choice(['coin', 'sack', 'money']))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)" it says "   File "c:\Users\Sebi\Desktop\mOVE\test.py", line 77, in main
    FallingStuff((randint(50, 550), -TILESIZE), falling_stuff, sprites)
  line 50, in __init__
    self.image.fill(choice(['coin', 'sack', 'money']))
ValueError: invalid color name

Comment: The fill function excepts a Color object, an integer tuple or a color name as argument, as it's used to fill the surface with a solid colour. To use your loaded images, just set them as image attribute, like self.image = Sack

Comment: Okay nice, works now! Got my images and the idle state of my character in it. Only thing i want to change is the hitbox. I want the player only to get points when the icons hit the hand of my character. Is this possible with your code or do i have to add a hitbox code? And second question. I want my character t have a walking animation so if he walks left he got some different states and right the same way. I put a for loop after the keys but it doesnt work like this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @sloth just added m actual code now down below

Comment: @xAskadia I added an example on how to add a hitbox and animations. enjoy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227700/discussion-between-xaskadia-and-sloth).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should consider to use "ae, oe, ue" or just the English translations instead of "ä, ö, ü", this can cause a few problems. Also, why don't you have included pygame?
Second of all, try not to use fixed values for window size, if you want to change it later on, you have to change a few values and easily run into problems when you forget one. I would recommend using a variable for width and height you can change later on.

But to your specific problem:
I think the reason you don't see any objects falling is that there are none. The part of your code that actually runs is in the while-loop and as long as I didn't miss anything, neither is there anything about your dropping objects, nor about them falling (any kind of acceleration or velocity).
Also I would highly recommend (as the comment of "oskros" already said) to test your code before asking. This is also an important part of programming and can be done like this for example:
You go in every function and write a "print" statement there, so you know that this function has run (by the output on the console). If one doesn't run, try to look at the point where it was supposed to be run and go on fixing from this point.
You can apply this technique to basically any debugging, stackoverflow is mostly for asking more specific questions and not "why does this not work, can you fix my code?" (at least for a whole program)

Comment: Your problem is that the part of actually creating the objects is not executed. All of the stuff in the while-loop is being executed, but what is not in there is anything about your objects your figure has to catch ;)
Also, use my advise of adding print statements, so you can see exactly what is being executed in which order (and therefore what is not).
If your problem remains, just try splitting it up further, because that is one essential part in programming :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame.freetype
from random import choice, randint
pygame.init()

RESOLUTION = 900, 780
FPS = 60
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 600
FALLING_SPEED = 400

coin = pygame.image.load('coin.png')
coin = pygame.transform.scale(coin, (60, 60))

sack = pygame.image.load('sack.png')
sack = pygame.transform.scale(sack, (60, 60))

money = pygame.image.load('schein.png')
money = pygame.transform.scale(money, (60, 60))

char = pygame.image.load ("L1.png")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Assets/R1.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R2.png'), pygame.image.load('Assets/R3.png')]


bg = pygame.image.load('City.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (900,780))

pygame.mixer.music.load('Music/Titel.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, falling_stuff, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = char
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.falling_stuff = falling_stuff
        self.score = 0

    def update(self, dt, events):
        d = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: d -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: d += 1

        self.rect.move_ip(d * dt * PLAYER_SPEED, 0)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.rect.clamp_ip(display_rect)

        for stuff in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.falling_stuff, True):
            self.score += 1

class FallingStuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = choice([coin,sack,money])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        
    def update(self, dt, events):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, FALLING_SPEED * dt)
        display_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        if self.rect.top > display_rect.bottom:
            self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    dt, clock = 0, pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    falling_stuff = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((400, 700), falling_stuff, sprites)
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('ComicSans', 70)

    CREATE_STUFF = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == CREATE_STUFF:
                pygame.time.set_timer(CREATE_STUFF, randint(1000, 2000), True)
                FallingStuff((randint(50, 550), -TILESIZE), falling_stuff, sprites)

        screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
        font.render_to(screen, (30, 30), f'Score: {player.score}', 'white')
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```